# Add custom column to User Model using rails Clearance gem

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, clearance

I use the Clearance gem to add authentification to my website.
The standard User model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User
end
```

Now i want to add more properties to the User Model.
I created this migration:

```
class AddCustomernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :customername, :string
  end
end
```

After rake db:migrate, the database now has one more column for :customername

as next step I edited the User Model file so it looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User
  attr_accessor :customername
end
```

As the next step, I signed up a new user and used sqlite database browser to add the test string 'charly' in the customer name field for this user.

In my controller, i now want to create a user object and print it out to see if all the data is present.

```
thisUser = User.find(current_user.id)
puts thisUser.inspect
```

the console output is:

```
#<User id: 1, email: "test@test.de", encrypted_password: "0494a9b3b692acaea96ab57bed500adf26dbafa5", salt: "75c889d099438476204ce46b9cb406fb1f73423c", confirmation_token: nil, remember_token: "907b9bd600246d0b8dcc06a782457665f614b368", created_at: "2012-03-21 20:59:44", updated_at: "2012-03-21 21:12:59", customername: nil>
```

so customername is nil. somehow the data for this field is not pulled out of the database correctly.

what am i doing wrong?

Sorry,  I'm a rails beginner. Might be a very simple thing to do, but I tried hard and googled all day and couldn't get it to work, so I turn to the wisdom of stack overflow.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using attr_accessor in User model, use attr_accesible :customername and it will work. Because without attr_accessible, data will not be saved in your database and that is the reason you are getting nil value for the field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are editing the correct database when using the sqlite database browser? If so I would try modifying your user creation code to include the customer name rather than adding it using a separate tool and seeing if that helps.

Comment: tried this:

    thisUser = User.find(current_user.id)
    thisUser.customername = "Harry"
    puts thisUser.inspect

even if i do this the customername is still nil

Comment: i was able to get it done with another authentification gem, but still i would be interested what went wrong here